# Return all records from left table except

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables structures
**table_label**

```
 ________________
| id | name      |   
|____|___________|
|  4 |  NAME_1   |
|____|___________|
|  5 |  NAME_2   |
|____|___________|
|  6 |  NAME_3   |
|____|___________|
|  7 |  NAME_4   |
|____|___________|
|  8 |  NAME_5   |
|____|___________|
|  9 |  NAME_6   |
|____|___________|
```

**table_label_changes**

```
 __________________________
| id | before    | after   |
|____|___________|_________|
|  4 |     4     |    5    |
|____|___________|_________|
|  5 |     4     |    6    |
|____|___________|_________|
```

I'm trying to get all records from **table_label** except records where **table_label_changes.before** is equal to **table_label.id** and **table_label.id** is equal to **4**
So it should be something like:
all records from **table_label** minus IDs from column '**after**' where column '**before**' is equal to 4
In this example I should get:

```
 ________________
| id | name      |   
|____|___________|
|  7 |  NAME_4   |
|____|___________|
|  8 |  NAME_5   |
|____|___________|
|  9 |  NAME_6   |
|____|___________|
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_label tl
JOIN table_label_changes tc
  ON tl.id != tc.before
 AND tl.id = 4
```

return nothing

I tried `LEFT JOIN` also, but it return all records from left table.

How can I get response like above?

Comment: Should your output not also include `6, NAME_3` for that input rowset? If not, why not?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No, because I need records from table_label minus IDs from 'after' column where 'before' is equal to 4

Comment: You should edit above to clarify these relationships then. You have no indication that the `after` is involved in your current description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your question is not clear or the result you expected is not correct but I think this could help you:
(if you don't want the table_label.id == 4 you can add "and id <> 4" to where condition for table_label)

SELECT *
FROM table_label tl
WHERE id not in (SELECT after FORM table_label_changes WHERE before == 4)